# Oracle: column ambigously defined

Tags: database, oracle, performance

I am getting the following error. As far as I can see are all columns defined by table name, so I do not see why I get this error from my Oracle database.

```
   OCIError: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined:               SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT raw_sql_.*, rownum raw_rnum_
                raw_sql_
                WHERE rownum <= 25
              )
              WHERE raw_rnum_ > 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only thing that throws a red flag, the

```
ORDER BY offsakid desc
```

You alias one field to that name in your select:

```
OFFSAK.id offsakid,
```

But it could be an actual field name on one of your tables, and you should order by the underlying field - not the alias.

Comment: Other item, you have offbehandling.sakstype twice in your inner query which might cause a name collision in one of the outer selects. Alias one of them. Same with offutvalgid - you have two columns with the same name

Comment: Thanks bud! You helped me out there. The error is gone after cleaning it up :-)

Comment: Glad to have helped :)